# trouble solving the integral of certain functions

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have some trouble solving these

what is the integral of ln(cos(x))? 
and the integral of x^2 tan(x)?

I need the steps please

Comment: Both are examples of integration by parts. Try to work this out yourself.

Comment: @QingZhang Really? See [WA's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+tan(x)). Of course, WA does sometimes give results in an overly complex way, but it won't be easy to find [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2+tan(x)+from+0+to+pi%2F4) with only integration by parts... Same with [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(cos(x))) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log(cos(x))+from+0+to+pi%2F4) definite integral.

Comment: Are you sure you need the antiderivative? Computing $\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\cos x)\;\mathrm{d}x$ for example, is a well-known exercise which is much simpler that computing the antiderviative.

Comment: Ya i need the antiderivative

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think I was wrong. I thought tan(x) as arctant(x).